# How to update database when trying to update a property type enumerable?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I have a class called Ignicoes. This class has a property called "Estado" which is the type enumerable. Here is the class:

[image]

Then, on my index I want to be able to change the "Estado". Through this interface:

[image]

If I click in one of the buttons below ("Aceitar", "Recusar" or "Concluido"), the variable "Estado" is changed in  the database through PUT request.
Right now I'm doing it like this:

Here is when the function that updates the database is called:
[image]

Here is the function that updates the database when one of the buttons is clicked:

```
 function atualizaBD(idmarcador, novoEstado) {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${idmarcador}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Id: idmarcador,
                Estado: novoEstado
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                 connection.invoke("PostMarker").catch(function (err) {
                              return console.error(err.toString());
                 });
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("ocorreu um erro!")
            }
        });
     }
```

Here is the PUT method:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
    {
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        else
        {
            var dataDecisao = DateTime.Now;
            var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault(ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
            if (ig != null)
            {
                ig.Estado = ignicao.Estado;
                ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = dataDecisao;
            }
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Here is my output tab:

[image]

What happens right know is that when the button is clicked, the alert saying "ocorreu um erro!" appears, so the database isn't updated. I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you put some breakpoints? One to check with which parameters your reach your PUT method. And others to check where your code is throwing an error.

Comment: I placed some breakpoint in my code, but it doesn't stop, the app just keeps giving me the same alert, and nothing shows in the output tab or the error list tab

Comment: I'm having some problems with the breakpoints. I'm trying to solve it

Comment: Do you have swagger configured with your project? That could help check if there is a problem with your routing and the way you are calling the endpoint.

Comment: No I don't have swagger installed. Do you belive that would help. This part of my project used to work the only thing that I changed was the variable "Estado" that used to be a string and now it's an enumerable. I edited my question and add the output tab. Hope that will help understanding the issue.